# How to solve error kriging with external drift in R?

Tags: r, interpolation, rastervis, hydrotsm

I am trying to use kriging with external drift using hydrostm and hydrokrige. While, trying to interpolate, I can not interpolate well. I am using dem 30 m data. The code is following below:

```
library(zoo)
library(hydroTSM)
library(xts)
library(sp)
library(automap)
library(gstat)
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
library(raster)
bena.ts<- read.csv("EbroPPtsDaily.csv")
bena.gis = read.csv("EbroPPgis.csv")
bena.rs <- raster("DEM-UTM.tif")
bena.sa = readOGR("subBASIN-UTM.shp")
# Covert Raster to spatial grid data frame 
y <- as(bena.rs, "SpatialGridDataFrame")
class(y)
# Make Projection according to study area
p4s <- CRS("+proj=utm +zone=43 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=WGS84
+towgs84=0,0,0")
bena.ts1 <- as.numeric(bena.ts[180, 2:ncol(bena.ts)])
names(bena.ts1) = colnames(bena.ts[180,2:ncol(bena.ts)])
# Computing OK, over the spatial grid defined by the DEM
## Not run: 
x.ok <- hydrokrige(x.ts= bena.ts1, x.gis=bena.gis, 
                   X="EAST_ED50", Y="NORTH_ED50", sname="ID", 
                   formula=value~1,
                   subcatchments= bena.sa,
                   p4s= p4s, 
                   predictors=y,
                   ColorRamp= "Precipitation", 
                   main= "OK Precipitation on the Ebro",
                   arrow.plot= TRUE, 
                   arrow.offset= c(900000,4750000), arrow.scale= 20000,
                   scalebar.plot= TRUE, 
                   sb.offset= c(400000,4480000), sb.scale= 100000)
```

Comment: Please create a minimal self-contained reproducible example. You can use the examples in the help file of the methods used.

Comment: I am using my own data.

Comment: Yes, and that is a problem. That is now how you should ask questions on this forum.

Answer (score 0):

[bena.ts show daily precipitation values at different stations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjXK1.png)[bena.gis shows coordinates in UTM, elevation of points and subbasins name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jACvu.png)[bena.sa tells about shapefile of study area in UTM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/729g0.png)[bena.rs show DEM 30 m raster file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjQEC.png)

My issue is I can to interpolate it using elevation. I also conver my raster DEM 30 m file into spatial grid dataframe but still it do not show any results.Kindly guide me.